# Classical Particle Disintegration (Landau Lifschitz)

Tags: classical-mechanics

So I'm reading Landau's mechanics books and there was a question for the angular distribution of the resulting particles in the lab system (p.44 Q2 Chpt 4).  It says when $v_0>V$, it is given by

$$\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta\,d\theta\left(2\frac{V}{v_0}\cos\theta+\frac{1+\frac{V^2}{v_0^2}\cos2\theta}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V^2}{v_0^2}\sin^2\theta}}\right)$$
  I managed to find this but what I don't understand is why for the case that $v_0<V$ the difference instead is taken.  In the book it's explained by saying that as $\theta$ increases one value of $\theta_0$ increases and the other decreases, referring to this equation
$$\cos\theta_0=-\frac{V}{v_0}\sin^2\theta\pm\cos\theta\sqrt{1-\frac{V^2}{v_0^2}\sin^2\theta}$$
Where $v_0$ is the velocity of the particle in the Centre of Mass Frame, $V$ is the velocity of the Centre of Mass Frame, $\theta_0$ is the angle between the direction the particle travels velocity of the centre of mass frame when measured in the centre of mass frame, and $\theta$ is the angle between the direction the particle travels and the velocity of the centre of mass frame when measured in the Lab frame.
[image]

However, isn't the behaviour that Landau describes still present even when $V<v_0$?  I can't figure out what the difference between the two cases is other than when $V>v_0$ there exists some discontinuities in the graph of the function, but that doesn't explain why the difference is taken instead.  Could someone please explain to my why when $V>v_0$ the difference is taken instead?  Thanks!

Comment: What is $v_0$ and what is $v$? Just for those who cannot read the problem form the book ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular distribution in the L frame is the **sum** of contributions from the two possible $\theta_o$ angles. As $\theta$ increases, one of the $\theta_o$ angles decrease meaning $d(cos\theta_o)$ is negative. So minus the minus to get a positive.
A bit like integration gives an area below the x-axis as negative. If $A_1$ is the integral above the x-axis and $A_2$ is the integral below the x-axis, the total area is $A_1$ - $A_2$